# Where is the 'r/' coming from when I use shutil in this function?

Tags: python, shutil

```
def move_file(dirs,src,dst):

    src = src+".jpg"
    dst = item[1]+"/"+src

    print src
    # Moves the file        
    shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

move_file(dirs,item[0],item[1])
```

gives me this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'r/001.jpg'
```

Even when

```
item = ('001','Grass')
```

Where is the 'r/' coming from?

Comment: Wild guess: Item is a string, you're doing a substring operation on it.

Comment: Is that your real code? You're referring to `item` inside that function which seems very odd.

Comment: type(item) returns tuple. type(item[0]) returns string.

Comment: Why call `cp` as `mv`? very weird

Comment: Just stop using `item` from inside the function and some problems will probably disappear... And why does the funtion take `dirs` if it is not used at all?

Comment: Given that 'Grass'[1] is indeed 'r', I'd reconsider Bobby's answer.

Comment: @MAtI'm still new to programming, so I could just be doing odd things. This is my full code http://friendpaste.com/66StGvkPTUVSzMS2s3lh3I

Comment: @glglgl dirs is used in the actual code. I will stop using item in the function.

Comment: I've solved my problem. 

@glglgl you were right, I see where I've gone wrong, it works if I change the 'item[1]' in the function to dst. 

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your codes a bit messed up so its not entirely clear, but it looks like you are passing `item[1]` (== 'Grass') to move_files as `dst`.  You are also using item[1] inside move_files, which might be a typo, but if not then what is the value of `item` at that point?  Or should it be `dst`?  Either way, it looks like `item == 'Grass'` at the point that you're doing `dst = item[1]+"/"+src`, and so `item[1] == 'r'`.

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine that you don't show us the real code.

If you call with `move_file(dirs,item[0],item[1])`, the function is defined as `def move_file(dirs,src,item):` and you use `item[1]` inside the function, `Grass` will turn into `r`.